# Binding to an AIDL service in ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native, aidl, android-service-binding

We have developed a ReactNative android application and we want to bind to an AIDL service in one of our .aar dependencies.

How can I bind to an AIDL service in reactnative for Android ?

Comment: have u found any solutions .?

Comment: @Farhad , you found the solution